# Importing root application scss in Rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I am trying to import a scss file from the root application in to a rails engine. So I have 'application.scss' in 'app/assets/stylesheets' and I want to import that in 'administration/app/assets/stylesheets/applcation.scss'

I am using Rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

Add in routes.rb:

```
mount YourEngine::Engine => "/your_engine_path"
```

Add in application.scss file:

```
*= require 'your_engine_path/application.css'
```

Comment: It's the other way round.